# If $X$ is $G$-paradoxical then $G$ is $G$-paradoxical. Is my proof correct?

Tags: group-theory, analysis, proof-verification, group-actions

I am currently reading Stan Wagon's Banach-Tarski Paradox book, and this was left as an exercise to prove (converse of Proposition 1.10).

> Let $X$ be a set, and let $G$ act on $X$ with no nontrivial fixed points. If $X$ is $G$-paradoxical, then $G$ is $G$-paradoxical.

A hint was given with this, that I should transfer the paradoxical decomposition of a single orbit to $G$.

Here's how I've gone about proving this.

**Proof.** Let $A_{i},B_{j}\subseteq X$ and $g_{i},h_{j}\in G$ realize that $X$ is $G$-paradoxial (that is, $\left\{A_{i}\right\}\cup\left\{B_{j}\right\}$ is a partition of $X$ with $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}=X=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}$). Now, let $x\in X$. Then, the family of subsets consisting of $A_{i}^{*}=\left\{g\in G\mid gx\in A_{i}\right\}$ and $B_{j}^{*}=\left\{g\in G\mid gx\in B_{j}\right\}$ is a partition of $G$, as there are no nontrivial fixed points in the $G$-action on $X$, such that $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}^{*}=G=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}^{*}$. Therefore, $G$ is $G$-paradoxical. **QED**

My reasoning for the last equality: Since $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}=X=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}$, we would have $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}^{*}\mathcal{O}_{x}=\mathcal{O}_{x}=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}^{*}\mathcal{O}_{x}$ and, since the $G$-action has no nontrivial fixed point, there's a bijective correspondence $\mathcal{O}_{x}\leftrightarrow G$ given by $g\cdot x\leftrightarrow g$.

I feel like this is how one would prove this, but I need to know if this is correct. In particular, I feel the most unsure about the last equality statement, which is why I listed the reasoning above. Is this all correct?

EDIT:

Here's the final draft of my proof.

**Proof.** Let $A_{i},B_{j}\subseteq X$ and $g_{i},h_{j}\in G$ realize that $X$ is $G$-paradoxial (that is, $\left\{A_{i}\right\}\cup\left\{B_{j}\right\}$ is a partition of $X$ with $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}=X=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}$). Now, let $x\in X$. Then, the family of subsets consisting of $A_{i}^{*}=\left\{g\in G\mid gx\in A_{i}\right\}$ and $B_{j}^{*}=\left\{g\in G\mid gx\in B_{j}\right\}$ is a partition of $G$, as there are no nontrivial fixed points in the $G$-action on $X$. Since $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}=X=\bigcup_{1\leq j\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}$, we have $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}^{*}\mathcal{O}_{x}=\mathcal{O}_{x}=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}^{*}\mathcal{O}_{x}$ and there's a bijective correspondence $\mathcal{O}_{x}\leftrightarrow G$ given by $g\cdot x\leftrightarrow g$. So, stripping away the $x$ using this bijection, we have that $\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq m}g_{i}A_{i}^{*}=G=\bigcup_{1\leq i\leq n}h_{j}B_{j}^{*}$. Therefore, $G$ is $G$-paradoxical. **QED**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is simpler. Take any x and let A be its orbit. THe action of G works when completely restricted to A. Therefore the paradoxical decomp. must induce two subsets of A that each give the full copy of A. That is, we can simply restrict everything in sight to A. Then, because of the lack of fixed points, this induces what you want on G. A is simply a copy of G. A looks like {x, g1 x, g2 x, g3 x,...} where the g's enumerate g.

This is just a sketch, but it appears to be different than what you were doing.

SW

Comment: I think that's what I was doing (or trying). I implicitly restrict the decomposition to the orbit when defining $A_{i}^{*}$ since (equivalently) I'm taking $g$ such that $g\mathcal{O}_{x}\subseteq A_{i}$ for each $i$ (similarly for $B_{j}^{*}$). I do note below the proof that $\mathcal{O}_{x}$ is a copy of $G$, so we can strip away the $x$ and retain the paradoxical decomposition, making it a decomposition for $G$ (this was the part I felt uneasy about claiming).

Thank you. The fact that you essentially described what I was trying to do makes me feel much better about my proof.

Comment: Sorry if I did not read it in detail, but I guess all is well. And I guess my old hint is acceptable. But, as noted, we are now working on a second edition so if you see anything that is obscure, or could benefit from an elucidating phrase, (or is wrong!) please tell me. You can find my e-address atop by web page, stanwagon.com